# How to created custom TexboxFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html-helper

I have a textbox that insert only number and add comma separator in it.

I use this code in view

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TurnRatingCost, null, new { @class = "form-control",onkeyup= "javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);", onkeydown = "return ValidateNumber(event);" })
```

it is ok, but i want to convert this to custom TextboxFor with htmlHelper .

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an extension method on [HtmlHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```
public static class MyHtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
         this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
         Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
       // Your Custom code
    }
}
```

Then in your view you can use it as:

```
@Html.MyTextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
```

**Note:** Don't forget to `@using` the namespace of `MyHtmlHelpers` in your views

Comment: Thanks, how to add jqury in HtmlHelper

Comment: In above method we cannot add jquery in htmlhelper, for more details you can go thorugh https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: From above method we can create custom `htmlhelper`